# Windows 10: Have single instance of application across multiple desktops

Tags: windows-10, multiple-desktop, single-instance

I am new to the multiple desktops, and I am trying to allow a single instance of a program to show up in all of my desktops.

I would like to have programs such as Spotify, Outlook, and Skype open on all desktops, but have the same instance of that program showing on each one. I want them to be treated as "global" and show the same instance on all desktops and not be specific to any one desktop.

E.g: If I start Spotify on "Desktop 1"; I want it so I can still access the window and change the songs on "Desktop 2" without it switching back to "Desktop 1".

Is that possible? If it is, how do I get this to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest builds of Windows 10, you can click on Task View button (or Win+Tab), this will display all the opened windows, and right click on the window you want. There you get options to 'Show this window on all desktops' and 'Show windows from this app on all windows'. This will show the same instance across all the desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I've found so far is to pin Spotify in your [notification area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS8g4.png). It will still snap to the desktop Spotify is open on but it's better than nothing